# How to fix 'Rails.ajax' error in site Console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 different post types (news and articles). When i go to news and try to comment any news, nothing happen. In google chrome console it says:

```
POST /news/artifact-v-spiske-liderov-prodazh-steam-po-itogam-2018-goda/comments/ 404
rails-ujs.self-d109d8c5c0194c8ad60b8838b2661c5596b5c955987f7cd4045eb2fb90ca5343.js?body=1:7 
Rails.ajax @ rails-ujs.self-d109d8c5c0194c8ad60b8838b2661c5596b5c955987f7cd4045eb2fb90ca5343.js?body=1:7
Rails.handleRemote @ rails-ujs.self-d109d8c5c0194c8ad60b8838b2661c5596b5c955987f7cd4045eb2fb90ca5343.js?body=1:31
(anonymous) @ rails-ujs.self-d109d8c5c0194c8ad60b8838b2661c5596b5c955987f7cd4045eb2fb90ca5343.js?body=1:5
```

BUT! When i try comment in Articles type, all good, comments work. What is problem?

**My _form.html.haml:**

```
- if user_signed_in? && current_user.mute_to && current_user.mute_to > Time.current
%div
%strong
  = "Вы не можете писать комментарии до #{current_user.mute_to.strftime("%F %R")}"
- elsif user_signed_in?
= form_with model: [commentable, Comment.new], html: { class: 
local_assigns[:class], data: { target: local_assigns[:target] } } do |form|
.form-group
  = form.text_area :body, placeholder: "Напишите комментарий (минимум 3 символа)", class: "form-control"
.form-group
  = form.hidden_field :parent_id, value: local_assigns[:parent_id]
  = form.submit 'Отправить', class: "btn"
```

**My _comment.html.haml:**

```
- nesting     = local_assigns.fetch(:nesting, 1)
- max_nesting = local_assigns[:max_nesting]
- continue_thread = local_assigns[:continue_thread]
= tag.div id: dom_id(comment), class: "border-left pl-4 my-4" do
- if comment.deleted?
%strong [комментарий удален]
%small
  = link_to time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at), url_for(comment: comment.id, anchor: dom_id(comment))
%p [комментарий удален]
- else
- comments_user = comment.user
%strong.comments_user_line
  = fa_icon "user-circle", class: "mr-1"
  = link_to comments_user.nickname, user_path(comments_user), class: 'user_link'
%small
  = link_to time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at), polymorphic_path(comment.commentable, comment: comment.id, anchor: dom_id(comment))
= simple_format comment.body
%div.comments_block
- if user_signed_in? && current_user.mute_to && current_user.mute_to > Time.current
- else
  %small
    - if user_signed_in? 
      %btn.reply Отвеить
    - else
      = link_to "Отвеить", new_user_session_path
    = link_to "Удалить", [comment.commentable, comment], method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Вы уверены?"} if comment.user == current_user
  = render partial: "comments/form", locals: {                       |
      commentable: comment.commentable,                              |
      parent_id: reply_to_comment_id(comment, nesting, max_nesting), |
      class: "mt-4 d-none replies_form",                             |
      target: "reply.form"                                           |
    }                                                                |
 = tag.div id: "#{dom_id(comment)}_comments" do
- if continue_thread.present? && nesting >= continue_thread && comment.comments.any?
  = link_to "Открыть ветку", url_for(comment: comment.id, anchor: dom_id(comment))
- else
  = render comment.comments, continue_thread: continue_thread, nesting: nesting + 1, max_nesting: local_assigns[:max_nesting]
```

**My comments_controller.rb:**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

def create
@comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
@comment.user = current_user
if @comment.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @commentable }
    format.js
  end
else
  redirect_to @commentable, alert: "Ошибка :("
end
end

def destroy
@comment = @commentable.comments.find(params[:id])
return false unless current_user.id == @comment.user_id

@comment.destroy
redirect_to @commentable
end

private

def comment_params
params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :parent_id)
end
end
```

If i uncomment rails-ujs in application.js like this:

```
require rails-ujs
```

Then when i posting comment it will be say:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in News::CommentsController#create
Couldn't find News with 'id'=artifact-v-spiske-liderov-prodazh-steam-po-itogam-2018-goda

Extracted source (around line #7):

6  def set_commentable
7    @commentable = News.find(params[:news_id])
8  end
9 end
```

How i can fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first suggestion - comment `require rails-ujs` until you solve the issue. It will be easier to debug.

Then, the issue is that as a `params[:news_id]` you are passing news slug (`artifact-v-spiske-liderov-prodazh-steam-po-itogam-2018-goda`) instead of news id. One solution is to modify the code to pass news id as `params[:news_id`].

Another, a little big uglier solution, is to refactor `set_commentable` method in the `News::CommentsController` to something like this:

```
def set_commentable
  @commentable = News.find_by(slug: params[:news_id])
end
```

However, it might break other places where `set_commentable` is used.

Comment: try to    set_commentable in    News::CommentsController , not work :(

Comment: Please update your question with the changes and error that you receive